# Show that for every countable subset A of R , Int(A)=0

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Show that for every countable subset A of R ,Show Int(A)=$\emptyset$

**Try**

Let A=[0,1]
The closed interval is uncountable

But since  A$\subset $ R is countable and A is not ,each set
can’t be uncountable  so Int(A)=0

Help

Comment: The closed interval $[0,1]$ is not countable

Comment: Hint: show that all non-empty open sets are uncountable

Comment: What do you mean $A\in \Bbb R$ is uncountable and $A\subset \Bbb R$ is countable?

Comment: Oh, you are referring the second statement about A? I deleted it. Iwas trying to show an open interval existed in [0,1]. I guess it didn’t apply in the proof

Comment: Sorry, it was typo A is a subset of R, so A$\subset $ R not A$\in$ R

Answer (score 1):

I assume we're using the standard topology on $\Bbb R$.

The interior of any set $A$ is simply the union of all open sets that are contained within $A$.  So if $A$ has non-empty interior, it must contain some open interval.  But every non-empty open interval in $\Bbb R$ is uncountable, so if $A$ is countable, it cannot possibly contain any uncountable sets, so it cannot contain any non-empty open intervals.

That means there are no open sets contained within $A$, so $A$ has empty interior.

Comment: Correct. Thanks for clearing up confusion @RobertShore